# nunca entra en el constructor con parametros, en clase BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver

estoy intentando mostrar en un TextView los mensajes que entran en el telefono. Para ello utilizo la clase `SmsReceiver` que extiende de `BroadcastReceiver`. Para mostrar el mensaje en el TextView le paso dicho TextView al `SmsReceiver` en el constructor en el mainActivity: `smsListener = new SmsReceiver(t);` El `SmsReceiver` tiene dos constructores, uno con un parametro de tipo TextView y otro vacio. El problema es que siempre entra en el constructor vacio, y nunca en el que tiene el TextView, lo compruebo con un `Log.i("mensaje","constructor sin parametros");` para el constructor sin parametros y con un `Log.i("mensaje","constructor con parametros");` para el constructor con parametros. Tal como esta creado el objeto `smsListener`, deberia entrar en el constructor con parametros ya que le paso el TextView como parametro.Este es el MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    final private int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 123;
    SmsReceiver smsListener;
    TextView t;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        t=findViewById(R.id.texto);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            requestSmsPermission();
        else
        {
            smsListener = new SmsReceiver(t);
            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
            intentFilter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
            registerReceiver(smsListener, intentFilter);
        }

    }
    private void requestSmsPermission() {

        String permission = Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS;
        int grant = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);
        if ( grant != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            String[] permission_list = new String[1];
            permission_list[0] = permission;
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permission_list, 1);

        }
    }
}
```

y esta la clase SmsReceiver:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    private static final int ID_MEN_BARRA_NOTIF = 1;

    public SmsReceiver() {
        Log.i("mensaje","constructor sin parametros");
    }

    public SmsReceiver(TextView t) {
        Log.i("mensaje","constructor con parametros");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {
                // get sms objects
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                if (pdus.length == 0) {
                    return;
                }
                // large message might be broken into many
                SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                    messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                    sb.append(messages[i].getMessageBody());
                }
                String sender = messages[0].getOriginatingAddress();
                String message = sb.toString();
                String numeroTelefono = messages[0].getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                Toast.makeText(context, message+" del telefono: "+numeroTelefono, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i("message",message);
                // prevent any other broadcast receivers from receiving broadcast
                // abortBroadcast();
                enviarNotificacion(context);

            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Ya lo he resuelto. No entra nunca en el constructor con el parametro TextView porque no entra nunca en ese else, ya que el receiver esta definido en el Manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Tu lógica es un poco incorrecta, nunca inicializará el receiver ya que seguramente tu programa se esta ejecutando en un dispositivo con Android 6.0 o posterior :

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        requestSmsPermission();  //* siempre entra aquí.
    else
    {
        smsListener = new SmsReceiver(t);
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
        registerReceiver(smsListener, intentFilter);
    }
```

en este caso al requerir los permisos puedes modificar requestSmsPermission() :

```
private void requestSmsPermission() {

        String permission = Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS;
        int grant = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);
        /*if ( grant != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            String[] permission_list = new String[1];
            permission_list[0] = permission;
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permission_list, 1);

        }*/
    }
```

Una vez que el usuario responde al diálogo de permisos del sistema, no importando si aceptaste o no el permiso, este invoca la implementación de `onRequestPermissionsResult()` de tu app.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0 &&
                    grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permiso aceptado.

                //*Registra el Receiver!

            }  else {
                // Puedes explicar al usuario que no se acepto el permiso.
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```